# Qt EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: qt, user-interface, qt-creator, qt-designer

I encounter an EXC_BAD_ACCESS issue on my Qt project. The debugger shows that it is unable to access the memory of menuBar (Ui header line 78). The thing I don't understand is that if I use only 6 QAction items in my menubar layout, it does not give this error. It only happens when there are more than 6 QAction item (in this case, actionA7). Anyone have similar experience and it would be great if there is any solution. Thanks.

Ui header file:

```
    /********************************************************************************
    ** Form generated from reading UI file 'spreadsheet_mainwindow.ui'
    **
    ** Created: Thu Aug 23 10:22:10 2012
    **      by: Qt User Interface Compiler version 4.8.1
    **
    ** WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost when recompiling UI file!
    ********************************************************************************/

    #ifndef UI_SPREADSHEET_MAINWINDOW_H
    #define UI_SPREADSHEET_MAINWINDOW_H

    #include <QtCore/QVariant>
    #include <QtGui/QAction>
    #include <QtGui/QApplication>
    #include <QtGui/QButtonGroup>
    #include <QtGui/QHeaderView>
    #include <QtGui/QMainWindow>
    #include <QtGui/QMenu>
    #include <QtGui/QMenuBar>
    #include <QtGui/QStatusBar>
    #include <QtGui/QToolBar>
    #include <QtGui/QWidget>

    QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE

    class Ui_SpreadSheet_MainWindow
    {
    public:
        QAction *actionA1;
        QAction *actionA2;
        QAction *actionA3;
        QAction *actionA4;
        QAction *actionA5;
        QAction *actionA6;
        QAction *actionA7;
        QWidget *centralWidget;
        QToolBar *mainToolBar;
        QStatusBar *statusBar;
        QMenuBar *menuBar;
        QMenu *menuFile;

        void setupUi(QMainWindow *SpreadSheet_MainWindow)
        {
            if (SpreadSheet_MainWindow->objectName().isEmpty())
                SpreadSheet_MainWindow->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("SpreadSheet_MainWindow"));
            SpreadSheet_MainWindow->resize(400, 300);
            actionA1 = new QAction(SpreadSheet_MainWindow);
            actionA1->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("actionA1"));
            actionA2 = new QAction(SpreadSheet_MainWindow);
            actionA2->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("actionA2"));
            actionA3 = new QAction(SpreadSheet_MainWindow);
            actionA3->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("actionA3"));
            actionA4 = new QAction(SpreadSheet_MainWindow);
            actionA4->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("actionA4"));
            actionA5 = new QAction(SpreadSheet_MainWindow);
            actionA5->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("actionA5"));
            actionA6 = new QAction(SpreadSheet_MainWindow);
            actionA6->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("actionA6"));
            actionA7 = new QAction(SpreadSheet_MainWindow);
            actionA7->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("actionA7"));
            centralWidget = new QWidget(SpreadSheet_MainWindow);
            centralWidget->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("centralWidget"));
            SpreadSheet_MainWindow->setCentralWidget(centralWidget);
            mainToolBar = new QToolBar(SpreadSheet_MainWindow);
            mainToolBar->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("mainToolBar"));
            SpreadSheet_MainWindow->addToolBar(Qt::TopToolBarArea, mainToolBar);
            statusBar = new QStatusBar(SpreadSheet_MainWindow);
            statusBar->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("statusBar"));
            SpreadSheet_MainWindow->setStatusBar(statusBar);
            menuBar = new QMenuBar(SpreadSheet_MainWindow);
            menuBar->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("menuBar"));
            menuBar->setGeometry(QRect(0, 0, 400, 22));
            menuFile = new QMenu(menuBar);
            menuFile->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("menuFile"));
            SpreadSheet_MainWindow->setMenuBar(menuBar);

            menuBar->addAction(menuFile->menuAction());
            menuFile->addAction(actionA1);
            menuFile->addAction(actionA2);
            menuFile->addAction(actionA3);
            menuFile->addAction(actionA4);
            menuFile->addAction(actionA5);
            menuFile->addAction(actionA6);
            menuFile->addAction(actionA7);

            retranslateUi(SpreadSheet_MainWindow);

            QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName(SpreadSheet_MainWindow);
        } // setupUi

        void retranslateUi(QMainWindow *SpreadSheet_MainWindow)
        {
            SpreadSheet_MainWindow->setWindowTitle(QApplication::translate("SpreadSheet_MainWindow", "SpreadSheet_MainWindow", 0, QApplication::UnicodeUTF8));
            actionA1->setText(QApplication::translate("SpreadSheet_MainWindow", "A1", 0, QApplication::UnicodeUTF8));
            actionA2->setText(QApplication::translate("SpreadSheet_MainWindow", "A2", 0, QApplication::UnicodeUTF8));
            actionA3->setText(QApplication::translate("SpreadSheet_MainWindow", "A3", 0, QApplication::UnicodeUTF8));
            actionA4->setText(QApplication::translate("SpreadSheet_MainWindow", "A4", 0, QApplication::UnicodeUTF8));
            actionA5->setText(QApplication::translate("SpreadSheet_MainWindow", "A5", 0, QApplication::UnicodeUTF8));
            actionA6->setText(QApplication::translate("SpreadSheet_MainWindow", "A6", 0, QApplication::UnicodeUTF8));
            actionA7->setText(QApplication::translate("SpreadSheet_MainWindow", "A7", 0, QApplication::UnicodeUTF8));
            menuFile->setTitle(QApplication::translate("SpreadSheet_MainWindow", "File", 0, QApplication::UnicodeUTF8));
        } // retranslateUi

    };

    namespace Ui {
        class SpreadSheet_MainWindow: public Ui_SpreadSheet_MainWindow {};
    } // namespace Ui

    QT_END_NAMESPACE

    #endif // UI_SPREADSHEET_MAINWINDOW_H
```

header file:

```
    #ifndef SPREADSHEET_MAINWINDOW_H
    #define SPREADSHEET_MAINWINDOW_H

    #include <ui_spreadsheet_mainwindow.h>

    class SpreadSheet_MainWindow : public QMainWindow , public Ui_SpreadSheet_MainWindow
    {
        Q_OBJECT

    public:
        SpreadSheet_MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    };

    #endif // SPREADSHEET_MAINWINDOW_H
```

Cpp file:

```
    #include <QtGui>
    #include "spreadsheet_mainwindow.h"

    SpreadSheet_MainWindow::SpreadSheet_MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
        QMainWindow(parent)
    {
        setupUi(this);
    }
```

Main cpp file:

```
    #include <QtGui/QApplication>
    #include "spreadsheet_mainwindow.h"

    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
        QApplication a(argc, argv);
        SpreadSheet_MainWindow w;
        w.show();

        return a.exec();
    }
```

Comment: I can't find any error in the code you posted. Have you tried doing a full rebuild?

Comment: Where does it crash? Add the backtrace.